# Error when try to upload the WiFi 101 Firmware Updater

Tags: arduino

I'm using Arduino UNO and the library WiFi 101.

Simply when I try to upload the Firmware Updater sketch from File -> Examples -> WiFi101 -> Firmware Updater  I get this error:

Arduino: 1.8.12 (Linux), Board: "Arduino Uno"

data section exceeds available space in boardSketch uses 9908 bytes (30%) of program storage space. Maximm is 32256 bytes.

Global variables use 2145 bytes (104%) of dynamic memory, leaving -97 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

Not enough memory; see http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#size for tips on reducing your footprint.

Error compiling for board Arduino Uno.

This report would have more information with

"Show verbose output during compilation"

option enabled in File -> Preferences.

- The problem is clear which is this sketch needs more than the available memory in Arduino. But how can I solve that?

Thanks

Comment: The message says that you are trying to compile for an UNO.  Did you select the right board in the tools menu?

Comment: @Delta_G, WiFi101 shield is for Uno too

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure.  Never used the WiFi101.  Didn't know if it had a separate board entry.

Answer (score 0):

In the FirmwareUpdate sketch change `static const int MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE = 1024;` to a smaller size. Try 256.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried this before with 256 and 512 in order to make the sketch consume less memory and it was uploaded successfully, but when I go Tools -> WiFi101 -> WiFiNINA Firmware Updatere and press on (Update Firmware) I get an error saying (Make sure that FirmwareUpdate sketch is loaded to the board). So I think changing this in the sketch will make it unable to work even if it is uploaded to the board.

Comment: @AliAlzahrani, and why didn't you write about it in the question? do you even have the Arduino 101 shield on the Uno?

Comment: Yes I’ve got the WiFi 101 shield wired to the Arduino UNO and it is working well and I’m able to make it connected to the internet successfully and grab data from google.

Comment: if you open the Serial Monitor with FirmwareUpdater sketch, does it print "Failed to put the WiFi module in download mode"?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that the question was asked some time ago, however I have also been trying to update the firmware on the Adafruit WINC1500 WiFi Shield for Arduino using the Arduino Uno. I ran into the same problems mentioned here and on forums elsewhere.
After investigation it appears that the Arduino Uno restarts when the COM port is opened, and is not ready to receive serial comms for a short delay. The Firmware Updater tool doesn't provide enough time for the Arduino Uno to restart before sending the Hello message in the Test connection.

There are a few possible solutions:
Hardware modifications: If I understand correctly that the DTR line from the USB-Serial chip is connected to the Reset pin of the AVR then this could be temporarily cut.

A software solution was to use com0com (https://com0com.sourceforge.net/) to create a null modem connection between two purely virtual COM ports (e.g. COM13 <-> COM14), and a Python script to relay data from one end of this (e.g. COM13) to the Arduino (e.g. COM10). Then connect the Firmware Updater tool to COM14. The Arduino won't then reset and will be ready to receive communications from the firmware updater tool.

The Python script:

```
import serial
import time

with serial.Serial('COM10', 115200, timeout=1) as serUno:
    with serial.Serial('COM13', 115200, timeout=1) as serVirtual:
        time.sleep(2)  # wait for serial ports to initialise
        
        while (True):
        
            # Now read from each and send to the other
            while serVirtual.in_waiting > 0:
                b = serVirtual.read()
                serUno.write(b)  
                print("PC-U:" + str(b))
            
            while serUno.in_waiting > 0:
                b = serUno.read()
                serVirtual.write(b)
                print("U-PC:" + str(b))
```

I used the above software solution and have been able to use an Arduino Uno to update the firmware on Adafruit WINC1500 WiFi Shield for Arduino. Using Arduino IDE 1.8.19 and modifying the FirmwareUpdater sketch:

```
static const int MAX_PAYLOAD_SIZE = 256;
```

Answer (score -1):

The program you try to load onto the board is for `Arduino MKR1000` and UNO pin compatible boards with larger memory, if you want to update the firmware of a wifi101 shield attached to an UNO use the extension in

```
Tools -> WiFi101 / WiFININA Firmware Updater
```

If you need to install this here are the instructions

- Download the tool [from this page](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/WiFi101-FirmwareUpdater-Plugin/releases/latest).
- Create a tools folder in your sketchbook, if it doesn't exist yet.
- Unpack the zip archive into tools folder (it will look like .../Arduino/tools/WiFi101/tool/WiFi101.jar)
- Restart the Arduino IDE.

And this programm finds the [current version of the firmware](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/WiFi101/tree/master/examples/CheckWifi101FirmwareVersion)

Comment: but to use the updater you must first upload that sketch in the Arduino. and it is for Uno too. see my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think what you have mentioned will not work before the FrimwareUpdater sketch is loaded to the board. So this is the second step but I'm stuck now in the first step which is uploading the sketch.